# Not able to post data via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

two php variable in php code..

```
$areaid = filter_var($_GET["aid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$areaname = filter_var($_GET["aname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

    var uareaname = <?php echo ($areaname) ?>;
    var uareaid   = <?php echo ($areaid) ?>;

    post_data = {'userArea':userareaname,'userAreaid':uareaid}; Not able to post this data

    $.post('review_me.php', post_data, function(response){
```

Comment: Do `console.log(uareaname)` and `console.log(uareaid)` and what do you get?

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you check in firebug or something similar?

Comment: both have values 1 and almora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay replace these lines:

```
var uareaname = <?php echo ($areaname) ?>;
var uareaid   = <?php echo ($areaid) ?>;
```

With these line:

```
var uareaname = '<?php echo ($areaname) ?>';
var uareaid   = '<?php echo ($areaid) ?>';
```

String values must be in `quotes`. Otherwise it's considered as variables.

Comment: Thanks yaar life saver....thanks a lot ..